# mongoose need help writing query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with objects that a little cut down look like this:

```
{symbol: x, timestamp: 2323123132}
```

Now I receive an Array of "symbols" and two timestamps "fromdate" "todate" via a post request to the API. What I need to query and return back is:

Find and count the occurences of each symbol within that array where the timestamp is within the given date range "fromdate", "todate" and count how many times they occure.

so the output should look like this:

symbol: xy
count: 10

symbol yz
count: 5

and so on.

Could anyone provide me a hint of how to do that using mongoose and node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming timestamp1, timestamp2  and symbolsArray are the names of your variables and collection is the name of your collection, this could be your query:

```
collection.find({ "timestamp": { $gte:timestamp1, $lte: timestamp2 }, "symbol" : { $in : symbolsArray });
```

Comment: Glad it helped you. Please accept this answer, in that case.